# How to get a date in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My router.rb

```
resources :post_categories, :path => '', :only => [:show] do
    resources :posts, :path => '', :only => [:show]
end
```

I get what you need

```
/category/id
/category
```

How do I get this URL?

```
/category/2015/11/08/id
```

I wanted to do something like this

```
  resources :post_categories, path: '', only: :show do
    resources :posts, path: '/:year/:month/:day', only: :show, constraints: { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{2}/, day: /\d{2}/ }
  end
```

But I do not understand how to make workers

Comment: Have you considered putting the date as a query in the url? `/category/:id?date=2015-11-08`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to receive the URL of the form food / 2015/11/07/my_title